Poetry and Pyenv virtual environment "integration"
I read several posts about the possibility Poetry and PyEnv virtual env to coexist.
There are apparently two options:

set a variable, I did not understand where
specify the virtual environment with a poetry env use ...  statement.

I tried the latest, and the expectations where poetry would have not created any other directory but pinpointed to the current virtualenv directory to later use it as a repository for installing the packages.
However, judging from the output I received, this doesn't sound like it will be the case.
enter image description here
What am I doing incorrectly?
Or is it me having misunderstood the capability?
I've tried to launch a poetry env use ... to specify the current pyenv virtual directory.
